# Is there any way to view logger in google apps script without canceling run?

Tags: javascript, logging, google-apps-script

I notice every time I open the log in google script while the code is running, the run is canceled and also everything that was logged during the run is erased. This can get annoying because when code takes awhile to run or is stuck in an infinite loop it is impossible to see where the code is getting to and where it isn't during the run.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great solution to your problem:

https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog

Its an extension to the Logger API that allows you to feed your logs to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for that, Ill try it out.